# C++ template errors

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying out an implementation of a simple property system for C++ which I found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1615.pdf).

But the code won't compile.

```
template <class T, class Object, typename T (Object::*real_getter)()>
class ReadOnlyProperty
{
    Object * my_object;
public:
    void operator () ( Object * obj )
    {
        my_object = obj;
    }

    T operator()() const
    {
        return (my_object->real_getter)();
    }


    T get() const
    {
        return (my_object->real_getter)();
    }


    void set( T const & value );


    operator T() const {
        return (my_object->*real_getter)();
    }

    typedef T value_type;

};
```

I get multiple errors at the very first line. I'm using Xcode 4 and neither LLVM 2.1 or GCC 4.2 can compile this. What's the problem?

Comment: Minor, and unrelated, style note: it would be more idiomatic to use e.g. `operator=` to 'reseat' your proxy rather than `operator()`. Or using a named member (providing it along is also common), e.g. `reset` is commonly used for smart pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A member function pointer CAN be a template parameter, but in that case you should not put `typename` before:

```
template <class T, class Object, T (Object::*real_getter)()>
```

The other error is the call:

```
(my_object->real_getter)()
```

which should be:

```
(my_object->*real_getter)()
```

Comment: Ahh, you might be onto what the OP wants! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The template parameter list doesn't work like that. Template parameters must be one of: type names, types (with restrictions), or templates.

Maybe you mean to have a default type, like so?

```
template <class T,
          class Object,
          typename U = T (Object::*real_getter)()>
class ...
```

Here `U` defaults to a pointer-to-member-function, but you have to provide the complete signature including return type.

Or do you mean for `real_getter` to be a member typedef?

```
template <class T, class Object>
class ReadOnlyProperty
{
  typedef typename  T (Object::*real_getter)();
  //...
};
```

Or as @jmihalicza suggests, you want a value parameter of type `T (Object::*)()`?

```
template <class T, class Object, T (Object::*real_getter)()>
class ReadOnlyProperty
{ //...
};
```

Comment: The Standard name for those is *template non-type argument* (a.k.a non-type parameter), along with *template type arguments* and *template template arguments*. (Not to confused: templates are not types, but the template parameter kinds do not overlap.)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that clarification -- those are cool names indeed, and the "template template argument" is my favourite to this day :-)